# jQuery Button that can get clicked and unclicked but also gets unclicked if you click anywhere else

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

so I wanted to make a button that when you click it it looks depressed and when you click it again it doesn't anymore. Though I also wanted that, if you click anywhere outside of the button it ALSO doesn't look depressed anymore.

Here's my JavaScript code so far:

```css
if($('#taskbar-start').hasClass('taskbar-start-active') === false){
    $('#taskbar-start').click(function() {
        alert($('#taskbar-start').hasClass('taskbar-start-active'))
        $(this).toggleClass('taskbar-start-active');
        $(this).children().toggleClass('taskbar-start-frame-active');
    });
}
$(document).mouseup(function() {
    if($('#taskbar-start').hasClass('taskbar-start-active')){
        alert($('#taskbar-start').hasClass('taskbar-start-active'))
        $('#taskbar-start').removeClass('taskbar-start-active');
        $('#taskbar-start-frame').removeClass('taskbar-start-frame-active');
    }   
});
```

With that code the button gets depressed when I click it and undepressed when I click anywhere else, but if I click on the depressed button it gets undepressed for a moment and then depressed again (with the alerts, without the alerts it just stays depressed).

I've been researching and trying for a few hours now, I can't seem to find my issue. Sorry if the question is stupid, I'm still new to JavaScript/jQuery and still learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, instead of alerts, press F12 and start using the Developer Tools. Second, instead of alerts use `console.log` and the other bunch of useful commands you can find under `console` (like `console.time` and `console.timeEnd`) whick will appear in the Console tab. And third, the problem is that the `$(document).mouseup` function gets called when you `mouseup` the entire `document`, which includes your button. You should exclude that function when the element click is the button.

You approach is fine. I stopped his propagation when clicked the button, as @MuhhamadImran said, but changed the `mouseup` to `click` for it to work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('#taskbar-start').hasClass('taskbar-start-active') === false) {
        $('#taskbar-start').click(function(event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            $(this).toggleClass('taskbar-start-active');
            $(this).children().toggleClass('taskbar-start-frame-active');
        });
        $(document).click(function() {
            if($('#taskbar-start').hasClass('taskbar-start-active')){
                $('#taskbar-start').removeClass('taskbar-start-active');
                $('#taskbar-start-frame').removeClass('taskbar-start-frame-active');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Remember, when web developing, F12 is your friend.

Comment: I actually tried console.log before that, but that just doesn't... seem to work at all. I tried your solution, though, and unfortunately still have the same issue as before. Thank you, though!

Comment: @alex The console.log is not a fix to your problem, is an habit to verbose data correctly when web developing. As a programmer, using alert to verbose data is the worse thing you can do. Now, talking about the problem, if you share jsfiddle with your problem you will get more help. I'll try to fix the fiddle if you share it.

Comment: I know, that's not what I meant, I just meant that the console.log doesn't seem to appear in my console. However, I just tried again and it works now. I must've had some kind of typing error there, my bad.
Here is the jsfiddle, though https://jsfiddle.net/mL5r3fLg/3/

Comment: As @muhhamad said, `stopPropagation` is the best here: https://jsfiddle.net/Llorx/mL5r3fLg/4/ I updated it with click so it works better

Comment: In the updated fiddle, though, the button doesn't get un-depressed anymore if you click outside of it.

Comment: @alex You have to click the black area. jsFiddle iframes the output window so you can't access events of outer iframe if they are not on the same domain, because of browser security. Check GIF: http://i.imgur.com/46QUA9Q.gifv New fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Llorx/mL5r3fLg/5/

Comment: Oh, that's really weird, is there a chance you might have sent me the wrong jsfiddle? I tried again, clicking the black area, it still doesn't work for me. Neither does it if I use the code in my file.

Comment: Ah, I just saw the new fiddle and it works now! thank you!
Edit: okay nevermind, in the new fiddle the button, again, stays depressed if you click it again :(

Comment: @alex Oh yeah, it has `mouseup` instead of `click`. Just change it and it should work.

Comment: @alex Yay. Can you upvote or accept the answer if it helped you?

Answer (score 0):

Stop event bubbling when you click the button so it doesnt bubble up to the document to re-init the events/classes,

below is the corrected code, only one line added in button click function

```
if($('#taskbar-start').hasClass('taskbar-start-active') === false){
        $('#taskbar-start').click(function(event) {
            event.stopPropagation()
            alert($('#taskbar-start').hasClass('taskbar-start-active'))
            $(this).toggleClass('taskbar-start-active');
            $(this).children().toggleClass('taskbar-start-frame-active');
        });
    }
    $(document).mouseup(function() {
        if($('#taskbar-start').hasClass('taskbar-start-active')){
            alert($('#taskbar-start').hasClass('taskbar-start-active'))
            $('#taskbar-start').removeClass('taskbar-start-active');
            $('#taskbar-start-frame').removeClass('taskbar-start-frame-active');
        }   
    });
```

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. I still get the same issue as before, unfortunately. Thank you, though